# Add progress bars to the badges on the Badges page

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-progress

It would be good if we add a progress bar to some of our badges on the Badges page to indicate the user how they have gotten far to it before the users gets that badge immediately. I've drawn what I want on the right of the "Question with 10,000 views".

[image: with progress bars]

Comment: You can already see badge progress for all badges in the badge selection screen in your profile, for the badges that support it. Note that that doesn't include all badges, since not every badge is trackable for technical or inherent reasons. Having missing progress bars for those badges will get confusing.

Comment: There's not a whole lot of extra room on the badges page. I'm not sure how well this would fit.

Comment: @pizzastaticvoidmain Maybe add some spacing?